# Does Istio virtualService always needs a DestinationRule?

Tags: istio

I'am new to Istio and I just started to play arround with VirtualServices. In the doc, examples show the creation of virtualService AND destinationRule

but [here](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-canary/), in this blog article about canary deployment, they just create a virtualService :

`kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
    - helloworld
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v1
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v2
      weight: 10`

So, without destinationRule, how Istio knows that `subset:v1` corresponds to the `version:v1` label of the helloworld deployment ?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

If the `VirtualService` uses `subsets`, you have to define the `subsets` in a `DestinationRule`.

I have opened an issue to fix the blog post https://github.com/istio/istio.github.io/issues/2152. Thank you for pointing to the problem.